# Launch Exe from UWP app

Tags: exe, uwp, appdata

I have a UWP app and I need to launch an .Exe file from the users %appdata% folder.

I don't know how to find %appdata% or how to launch Exe files.

I have looked all over but none of the solutions I have worked for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is no supported mechanism to launch random EXEs in a Universal Windows App. You can launch apps via a URI scheme or a file association if one is registered.

What does the EXE do that you're trying to launch? Is it your own program or is it someone else's? And do you want to do this for yourself or do you want to put it in the store?

Comment: It's for myself. I wanted the program to launch a XNA game, and I wanted the live tile. I know there's mono-game but it doesn't work for 32-bit which I sadly have.

Comment: If it is for yourself then try creating a dummy URI or file association in Control Panel, then launch it via `Windows.System.Launcher`

Answer (score 3):

As for 2016 you problem can be solved by [Desktop app converter](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop). So you can add live tile directly to your XNA game.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch .exe through socket connection.
Here is my sample code.

[Here is my sample code.](https://github.com/yosukeueda33/UWPinvokeEXEsample)
But as ad1Dima said, DAC is best solution.